# BIOSの設定画面で仮想化支援機能の設定が出来ない

Tags: ubuntu, docker, virtualbox

docker-machineを使用しようとした際に以下のエラーが出ました。

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. 
Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"
```

BIOSの仮想化支援機能をOnにしようと思ったのですが、
そもそも設定する項目があらわれません。
どのようにしたら項目があらわれるようになるでしょうか。

手順は、以下です。
1. 起動中に`F2`を押す
2. BIOS設定画面を表示
3. `Advanced`タブを表示
4. `Intel Virtualication Technology`の項目が無い

Windows上でVMwareでUbuntuを使用しています。
WindowsはVirtual Ceckerで確認したところ仮想化支援機能に対応しています。

Comment: Docker自体はWindowsではなくUbuntu上で動作させようとしていると言うことでしょうか？また、VMwareとはVMware Workstation Playerのことであってますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
はい。Ubuntu上で動作をさせようとしています。
VMwareはVMware Playerのことです。

Comment: BIOSの話になると、使っているマザーボードについての情報が必要になる気がします

Comment: @PicoSushi ありがとうございます。覚えておきます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

仮想ゲスト上で仮想化支援機能を有効にし、さらに仮想化することNested Virtualization(入れ子仮想化、Nested VMsとも)といいます。この機能を有効にするには、基本的に仮想ゲスト自体の設定を仮想化ソフト上で行う必要があります。VMware Workstation Playerについては下記の公式、およびその翻訳に設定方法が載っていますので、参考にしてください。

[Running Nested VMs |VMware Communities](https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8970)
[Running Nested VMs  - Qiita (上記の翻訳)](https://qiita.com/tsukamoto/items/ad0d34894dd55761478b)

上記に書かれていない古いバージョンではNested Virtualizationがサポートされていません。その他、有効にするための条件も書かれていますので、確認してください。なお、Workstation Playerについて12以降については記載がありませんが、11とほぼ同等思われます(未確認です)。

Comment: 上記のサイトを参考にして、解決が出来ました。ありがとうございます。

備忘として、手順を残させてください。
「仮想マシン設定の編集」
→「ハードウェア」タブの「プロセッサ」を選択
→仮想化エンジンの優先モードを「Intel VT-x/EPT または AMD-V/RVI」に設定
→「Intel  VT-x/EPT または AMD-V/RVIを仮想化」にチェック

実際には、BIOSの設定画面は変わりませんでしたが、実行したいコマンドは実行できるようになりました。